# Create charts with interlaced data

Tags: excel, charts

Is it possible to create charts using interlaced data in Excel 2007?

Example: 3 parts are in a test, and the app that collects data from them creates a CSV file with one line per part.

Example:

```
Part#,Voltage,Freq,Mode
001,3.453,6546,1000
002,3.542,6543,1000
003,3.484,6654,1000
001,3.453,6543,1000
002,3.642,6764,1000
...etc.
```

I would like to create a chart that plots the data from these three parts in their own series. I know that autofilter can be used to hide data from parts I don't want, but that only allows me to see one part at a time.

Furthermore, I would like to automate this process to create charts for an arbitrary number of parts. Is there a filter function I can use somewhere?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you'd like to chart. Obviously, you can import the CSV to excel and have the comma delimiter separate each of the 4 items into 4 separate columns. With this information you want to chart what? The frequency that each Part# shows up? You sound like you want a table, or a pivot table, not a chart by your explanation of filtering. If you could be more clear in what your end result needs to be, it would be helpful.

Comment: I know about the TextToColumns. That's not the problem.

Perhaps this will explain it better: I want to make a chart with each part having its own data series on the same chart, ex the voltage for Part 001, Voltage for Part 002, and the Voltage for Part 003. The problem is that the data for all the parts is interlaced into one column, just like you see in my example. I need to separate them out somehow.

Is there some method to make a data series with just the values for part 001, another for part 002, and another for part 003?

Comment: There can be several hundred and up to a couple thousand lines in the actual data, and a few dozen different parameters I might want to chart out. Doing this manually is basically impossible. I want to find a way to automate it with a macro.

Before I can do that though, I need to know if it's possible to do at all.

Comment: I apologize, I still don't quite understand. If you use `data - from text` to import the csv, it will create a sheet where the comma delimiter separates the data into 4 columns. This should solve your first problem. Your second problem is sorting the data by part number and then plotting an attribute for each part on a graph? Have you tried a pivot chart? Or am I still misunderstanding? It looks like in your example data the parts show up more than 1 time, maybe that's what is throwing me.

Comment: A pivot chart looks to be exactly what I need, though it seems like it'd be a pain to automate. I'll have to look into that more.

Comment: A pivot table looks to be really hard to program, are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you post an example of your data?

Comment: I can't post a full sample, but I can give a stripped down one.

http://www.freewebs.com/jiggy-ninja/Sanitized%20Data%20Sample.asc

It's saved as tab delimited from Excel. There are 4 parts, and only one piece of data is shown (a voltage reference reading), but the real file can have several dozen.

I want to have the dat afor parts 0082, 0116, 0172, and 0230 show up as their own lines on the same graph. I don't know how to make this happen since they are all in the same column, and pivot charts look complicated to program.

I know how to use AutoFilter, but that only shows one at a time.

Comment: Since I'm using a macro anyway, I could just scan down picking every nth cell and set the data range, but that seems inelegant, and sometimes dumps are missed, throwing off the count.